# What are the consequences of doing a blocking call in `tExcTask`?

Tags: vxworks

Let say I add a job `excJobAdd(myFunc, ...)` which will get scheduled in the `excTask`. In the function I do a blocking call:

```
int myFunc(...) {
  ...
  semTake(...)
  ...
}
```

Assuming I never come out of the blocking call. What are the consequences?

One thing I can think of is:

- All subsequent jobs to `excTask` will be blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though tExcTask is not a real ISR / exception, it still executes in ISR context. Try to do a blocking call in ISR context is illegal and raises the corresponding errno.